# Uid/GID mismatch

Tags: permissions, magento

I have been trying to setup the magento site but have been playing around with permissions which has resulted in the following error in the suexec.log

```
[2014-04-25 08:20:56]: uid: (5015/web12) gid: (5011/client7) cmd: .php-fcgi-starter
[2014-04-25 08:20:56]: target uid/gid (5015/5011) mismatch with directory (33/33) or program (33/33
```

Any ideas how i can get it so that the uid and gid match?

I have done id www-data and 5011/client7 is against that user.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `httpd` is trying to run `.php-fcgi-starter` script using [**suEXEC**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html) as user `web12` group `client7` (uid:5015,gid:5011) and script or directory owner has uid:33 and gid:33.

`suEXEC` allow to run script with a user/group defined by [**SuexecUserGroup**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_suexec.html#suexecusergroup) directive. Target user/group must be the same as the user/group that owns script and directory.

Probably you need to run:

```
chown -R web12:client7 /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12
```

`suEXEC` performs a lot of check before run a script, here is useful [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html#model) for more details.

Comment: where is the php-fcgi-starter located? if i run the above command will it interfere with other websites that are on the same server?

Comment: try `find / -name ".php-fcgi-starter"` this will give you the right path. It seems that you installed [mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html), I don't know if some of yours applications relies on this module.

Comment: Running that command shows lots of files which runs through the whole system it seems

Comment: Oh! How many file did you found? Unfortunately the error message did not show path. Could you post on http://pastebin.com/ `find / -name ".php-fcgi-started" -exec ls -l {} \;` so it shows file properties.

Comment: Again too Many files

Comment: Sorry, you got error, right? try `find /var -name ".php-fcgi-started" -exec ls -l {} \;`

Comment: No errors but found var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12 where there is the php-fcgi-starter if that helps

Comment: Did you try chown command? Could you post `ls -l /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12` command output?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 30 2014-10-04 21:48 web12

Comment: Probably www-data as uid and gid 33, that is why you got error. You can see this with `id www-data`

Comment: So running the chown command will fix it?

Comment: It should fix. How many files are in those folder? If you are worried, you could change only .php-fcgi-started and directory web12 too, and than let's see if it work. `chown web12:client7 /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12` and `chown web12:client7 /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-started`

Comment: Now all websites have gone down really need help now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17631/discussion-between-letizia-and-tjhack).

Comment: All sorted apache had stopped thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you.